# Request blocked by CORS policy

Tags: php, ajax, rest, slim

I have an API built with PHP Slim Framework 3 and testing the API with Postman everything is working great but when I put the app on the server and tried to make an Ajax Call I've got this message:

> Failed to load https://api.mydomain.net/usuario/autenticar?xAuthClienteID=2&xAuthChaveApi=3851b1ae73ca0ca6e3c24a0256a80ace&login=admin&senha=teste: Redirect from 'https://api.maydomain.net/usuario/autenticar?xAuthClienteID=2&xAuthChaveApi=3851b1ae73ca0ca6e3c24a0256a80ace&login=admin&senha=teste' to 'https://api.mydomain.net/404.html' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

I've looked up Slim docs on how to enable CORS on my server and applied it on the function I use to return JSON. It looks like this:

```
public function withCustomJson($meta = null, $data = null)
{
    if (isset($data)) {
        $finalResponse['data'] = $data;
    }

    $finalResponse['meta'] = array(
        'status' => (isset($meta['status']) ? $meta['status'] : null),
        'message' => (isset($meta['message']) ? mb_convert_encoding($meta['message'], "UTF-8", "auto") : null)
    );

    $response = $this->withBody(new Body(fopen('php://temp', 'r+')));
    $response->body->write($json = json_encode($finalResponse));

    // Ensure that the json encoding passed successfully
    if ($json === false) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(json_last_error_msg(), json_last_error());
    }

//Allowing CORS as Slim docs states
    $responseWithJson = $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')
                ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
                ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');

    if (isset($meta['codStatus'])) {
        return $responseWithJson->withStatus($meta['codStatus']);
    }
    return $responseWithJson;
}
```

And here's what my Ajax call looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      try {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.mydomain.net/usuario/autenticar',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
              xAuthClienteID:'2',
              xAuthChaveApi: '3851b1ae73ca0ca6e3c24a0256a80ace',
              login: 'admin',
              senha: 'teste'
            },
            ContentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(response){
              console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
      }
      catch(err) {
        alert(err);
      }
    </script>
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Appreciate any help.

Comment: show us your route definition in slim

Comment: You need to also include a route handler for the OPTIONS pre-flight request that returns the CORS headers.